# positioning content around dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use Jquery ui datepicker 1.10.3 with jquery 2.0.2.  Also using requirejs, Zurb foundation as the base styles of the form and the grid.

This sounds like a datepicker issue, but it is simply the use-case and I have to position other random elements with the same problem.

I'm only trying to get this to work in the IE 9,10 and the latest few chrome versions.

I have the datepicker wrapped in a knockout binding.

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};

                $(element).datepicker(options);
                ....
```

I have two large pages.  The first page is very large form, several hundred inputs and everything works great.

In the second page is the start of the problem.

It has numerous large forms that are on panes that are moved in front of each other.  This dynamic page breaks the jquery ui positioning.

I tried to manually position the datepicker by adjusting the margins on the beforshow and it works for the muilti pane page in IE but not chrome.  And it breaks the simple page.

I cant modify the _checkOffset function in jqueryui.  I want to keep how the picker will be above or below based on where its at in the page.

**What is the right way to find the proper position across chrome and IE?**

This is my modified binding.  Works on muilti page in IE, breaks in chrome and the simple page is broke.

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
                debugger;
                options.beforeShow = function (textbox, instance) {
                    //debugger;
                    instance.dpDiv.css({
                        //marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                        //marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 'px',
                        marginTop: ($(document).scrollTop() || document.body.scrollTop) + 'px'

                    });
                };

                $(element).datepicker(options);
                ....
```

the positioning of the muilti page ccs looks like this.  Using Modernizr with prefixes.

```
.perspective {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px; }

.pane {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; }

.current {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1; }
```

so the markup is something like this.

```
<div id="panel_container" class="perspective">

    <div id="Pane3Container" class="pane">
        @Html.Partial("_Form3")
    </div>

    <div id="Pane2Container" class="pane current">
        @Html.Partial("_Form2")
    </div>

    <div id="Pane1Container" class="pane">
        @Html.Partial("_Form1")
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try using iquery v 1.9 it is more compatible with ie

Comment: jquery ui 1.9.2 _checkOffset function is identical to 1.10.3  Let me switch out jquery 2.0 and see.

Comment: Still no luck with this.  =(